# Why is text clearing from the text field of a combobox if message is displayed?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm working in VB.NET, Visual Studio 2017.  I have a combobox with DropdownStyle = Dropdown.  If the user types something invalid in the text field of the combobox (invalid means it doesn't match a value in the combobox) then we display a message and then return focus to the text field with the text highlighted, so they can see what they typed.  The message is displayed from the Validating event.

This works fine if they don't open the dropdown.  If they do open the dropdown and, while it is open, they type in an invalid entry, the message displays but the entry they typed clears.
I have put in debug statements to see what events are firing.  Before the message displays, I get a DropDownClosed (text is still there), then a TextChanged (text is still there), then a second TextChanged (text is now empty).  I think something about losing focus to display the message may be triggering something, but I can't figure out what.
I can save off the text and then replace it after the message displays, but while the message is up, the text field is blank.
Any ideas?

Comment: We shouldn't have to ask you to post the relevant code. We can't test your code if we can't see what your code is.

Comment: Can you show us at least the Validating event.  Guessing some where in there you cancelling it somewhere which is meaning the data is no longer valid, hence being cleared

Comment: I'll post the code below.  Because while I have partially fixed the issue, there's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't understand the series of events that causes the problem, I found a solution.  Just before the message is displayed from within the Validating event of the combobox, I set focus to the combobox.  I'm guessing that tabbing away from the invalid entry loses focus, and because the dropdown is open, it then closes which somehow clears the entry.  Go figure.

Here is the code from the validating event:

```
            If testInList Then
                ResultTextBox.Enabled = True
            Else

                TestComboBox.Focus
                'If test is not in combobox, display message.
                MyUtility.MicroUtilities.DisplayMessage(
                    My.Resources.RES_MSG_INVALID_TEST, MessageBoxIcon.Information, , , True)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
```

The "TestComboBox.Focus" line has fixed the issue of the text disappearing.  However, if the user's invalid entry is a partial match for an item in the dropdown, then the text in the text field of the combobox is updated to that item, so now it looks like they typed a valid entry but are getting an message that it's invalid.  For example, if there is an entry in the dropdown of "NAMC" and they type "NA" (with the dropdown open) and tab away, the entry changes to "NAMC".
Any ideas on how to prevent that?

p.s. The AutocompleteMode is set to None.

Comment: Doing e.Cancel = True in your validation event is what is clearing it.  This says the input is not valid, so clearing for the user

Comment: When I step through the code, the text clears before I get to the e.Cancel.  It clears when I execute the line which displays the message.

Comment: And to verify that it is not the particular message code that causes the problem, I replaced it with a simple MsgBox.  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

So again, I don't understand the sequence of Events that causes the issue, but I've found something that works.  If I move the new "TestCombobox.Focus" line outside of the If condition, the text remains in the text field before, during and after the message displays:

```
            TestComboBox.Focus()
            testInList = TestEntryValid()

            If testInList Then
                EnableResultFields(True)
            Else
                'If test is not in combobox, display message.
                MyUtility.MicroUtilities.DisplayMessage(
                    My.Resources.RES_MSG_INVALID_TEST, MessageBoxIcon.Information, , , True)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
```

This moves the .Focus before TestEntryValid, but I don't see anything in there that would trigger any events:

```
Private Function TestEntryValid() As Boolean
    Dim item As String = TestComboBox.Text
    Dim validTest As Boolean = False

    If item.Length > 0 Then
        Dim index As Integer = TestComboBox.FindStringExact(item)
        If index > -1 Then
            validTest = True
        End If
    End If

    Return validTest

End Function
```

If anyone can explain why this works, I'd love to know.  If not, thanks to everyone who responded!